# How to move set of files having multiple extension to another directory using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to move set of specific files having different extension to another folder.

I have following filtered files in the directory.

```
file1.txt
file2.xml
file3.dll
```

I have kept the above files in the variable `$files` and I need to move each of files to another folder.

Below is the code I tried.

```
foreach ($fileType in $files) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Files -Filter "$fileType*." -Recurse |
        Move-Item -Destination C:\Dest
}
```

I am getting following error

```
Get-ChildItem : Illegal characters in path.
At line:1 char:38
+ ... lude_files){Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Files
```

Appreciate if anyone can help on this?

Comment: The code and sample data you posted wouldn't throw that error. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem, test-run that code to ensure that it actually does demonstrate the problem, then [edit] your question and copy/paste *that* code as well as the full error thrown by that code.

Comment: What is $filetype?

Comment: @js2010 The loop variable.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this

```
ls C:\files | Foreach {
        Move-Item -Path C:\files\$filetype -Destination C:\dest
}
```

Comment: HI @Modro, Thanks for your answer. However this not working. It throws following error

Move-Item : An object at the specified path C:\Files\    does not exist

I tried with many options that already posted relate to this, but nothing is working for me. 
Let me know please if there any way to move list of files to another folder
Appreciate for the help

Answer (score 0):

If all the files you are after share a common 'starts-with' name like `file` as in your example, the below should do what you want. It uses the `-Include` parameter where you can add an array of (in this case) extensions to look for.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Files' -Filter 'file*' -Include '*.txt','*.xml','*.dll' -Recurse |
    Move-Item -Destination 'C:\Dest'
```

<sup>Note: the `-Include` parameter only works when also used together with the `-Recurse` switch, OR by appending `\*` after the path (like in `C:\Files\*`)</sup>